# Recursive "Extension context invalidated" error in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I cannot find cause in extension (Even after removing the affected files it persists...)

Here's the error that I am seeing (Ir just loops with this every second)

```
let pingTimer = setInterval(ping, 100);
let pingUtilities = new PingUtilities();

function ping() {
  let port = chrome.runtime.connect();
  if (port) {
    pingUtilities.checkTitleInLinkedIn();
    pingUtilities.appendBookMarkInPing();
    pingUtilities.checkCounter();
    port.disconnect();
    return;
  }
  clearInterval(pingTimer);
  pingUtilities.onDisabled();
}
```

> Uncaught Error: Extension context
>   invalidated. Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated. Uncaught
>   Error: Extension context invalidated. Uncaught Error: Extension
>   context invalidated. Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated.
>   Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated. Uncaught Error:
>   Extension context invalidated.

Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Use `try { /* function body here */ } catch (e) {}`.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm - Unfortunately it still persists, suspecting it may relate to the version of Chrome somehow.

Users on version 71 aren't affected but version 72 seems to show this error. :/
I'm really stumped on this one. :[

Comment: Assuming you've used try/catch correctly, it probably means the error is caused by a different code. BTW it's not clear why you use this pinging.

Comment: Update - @wOxxOm | We managed to get your solution to work in the end.

Thank you so much! :]

Comment: Also, if it helps - This ping is used to check wether or not the extension is referencing the correct data from Chrome cache in relation to the Chrome browser tab.